# Can I repeatedly create & destroy random generator/distributor objects and destroy them (with a 'dice' class)?

Tags: object, c++11, random, dice

I'm trying out the random number generation from the [new  library in C++11](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) for a simple dice class. I'm not really grasping what *actually* happens but the reference shows an easy example:

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,6);
int dice_roll = distribution(generator);
```

I read somewhere that with the "old" way you should only seed once (e.g. in the *main* function) in your application ideally. However I'd like an easily reusable dice class. So would it be okay to use this code block in a `dice::roll()` method although multiple dice objects are instantiated and destroyed multiple times in an application?

Currently I made the generator as a class member and the last two lines are in the dice:roll() methods. It *looks* okay but before I compute statistics I thought I'd ask here...

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, but why would you want to create a new distribution every time if you only need dice rolls anyway? Oh by the way, `default_random_engine` is usually a `linear_congruential_engine`, which is very fast, but does have serial correlation. This may or may not be of interest for you.

Answer (score 1):

Think of instantiating a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG) as digging a well - it's the overhead you have to go through to be able to get access to water.  Generating instances of a pseudo-random number is like dipping into the well.  Most people wouldn't dig a new well every time they want a drink of water, why invoke the unnecessary overhead of multiple instantiations to get additional pseudo-random numbers?

Beyond the unnecessary overhead, there's a statistical risk. The underlying implementations of PRNGs are deterministic functions that update some internally maintained state to generate the next value.  The functions are very carefully crafted to give a sequence of uncorrelated (but ***not*** independent!) values.  However, if the state of two or more PRNGs is initialized identically via seeding, they will produce the exact same sequences.  If the seeding is based on the clock (a common default), PRNGs initialized within the same tick of the clock will produce identical results.  If your statistical results have independence as a requirement then you're hosed.

Unless you really know what you're doing and are trying to use correlation induction strategies for [variance reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_reduction), best practice is to use a single instantiation of a PRNG and keep going back to it for additional values.

Comment: So would the solution be to initialize the `std::default_random_engine generator` as a static member of the class? Or should it be put outside of the class?

Comment: Either would work just fine.  Which approach fits your needs better architecturally, or is "cleaner"?  I tend to like encapsulating dependencies, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: On seeding:  The C++ standard specifies precisely how each URNGs is to be seeded by default (unless the client specifies otherwise), and it is not by a clock.  It is by a standard-specified constant.  I.e. if you default construct a std-defined URNG, not only will you get the exact same sequence every time, but even if you port to another platform with another implementation, you will still get the exact same sequence every time.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the C++ standard and it's good to know.  That makes it even more imperative that the OP should not destroy and re-create the generator.